# One file for all translations

Tags: plugins

Is there any solution to translate just specific strings from plugins/theme from one central file? So the only translated strings are there (frontend) so editor of the website doesn't need to search trough all .MO files in Loco translate for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, this isn't possible, that's not how `mo` or `po` files work.**

A `po` file declares which locale it is for, and gets compiled into an `mo` file. You can't store more than 1 locale in the same file. Each file represents a single locale.

Keep in mind that these files aren't a WordPress thing. They're a `gettext` thing, and are used in lots of different applications, including other CMS's and even programs that have nothing to do with websites and servers.

So there is no WordPress based solution to your problem. Your search should continue elsewhere, specifically in the area of tooling